# Looping In Microsoft Dynamics NAV

Tags: dynamics-nav

I have two tables (MetreR)and (Billing):

`MReading
     date
     amount
     Billgen`

```
Billing
  date
  amout
  Customer No
```

I want to insert a record from MetreR table to Billing, anytime data or a record hits the MetreR table. It must run always. I don't want to use a job queue.

```
MetreR.RESET;
MetreR.SETFILTER(MetreR.Billgen,'%1',FALSE);
IF MetreR.FIND('-') THEN BEGIN
REPEAT


    Billing.INIT;
    Billing.ID:=MetreR."No.";
    Billing."Customer No.":=Customers."No.";
    Billing.Amount:=Billing.Consumption;

      MetreR.Billgen:=TRUE;

MetreR.MODIFY;
END;
```

UNTIL MetreR.NEXT=0;
END;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to extend or modify the MetreR table? if so then you should add your code to OnInsert on that table.

Comment: Yes i can modify the MetreR table and set the Billgen field to TRUE

Comment: I want the codeunit to check the MetreR table very second each day if the table is empty or has records.

Comment: @TheodulphSekyiQuainoo No way to do it without NAS or dedicated client opened 27/7.

Comment: I will encourage you to create another solution in which you use a NAS jobqueue to repeat your Codeunit as often as possible. By creating a Codeunit the way you are trying to, you are creating a piece of code which never exit and never releases its resources or sessions. If you want your update to be realtime, you should instead have either use the OnInsert method on the MetreR table or have the code inserting into the table invoke your codeunit with PowerShell. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn466416(v=nav.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can use OnInsert trigger on MeterR table. So that whenever there is any insert to that table, you can update Billing table through OnInsert trigger.